# Shape key transformation and armature

Tags: armature, shape-keys

I did a werewolf transformation using the shape key. Human to werewolf. So I rigged the human form, but as I feared, when I switched to werewolf form, everything is messed up. Is there a way to fix this and the vertices continue to follow the weight paint?

Sorry if I asked a stupid question or if I did it in the wrong place.
Thx in advance.

[image: The human form]

[image: Wherewolf]

[image: A random pose in human form]
[image: What happens when I change him]

Comment: Hello and welcome. You're in the right place and it is not a stupid question! Rig is very sensible to rest pose positions... but if possible you should upload your file or provide some significant images (what is "messed up" exactly ?) in your question so that some here could help you. You can upload the file using this site http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You should try to keep both at the same size (eventually, you can scale the werewolf after) and do so both models stay in the same floor plane. All that in edit mode (no scale at object mode). Also you can notice on the images that ww legs and arms are far from the bones: try to keep the mesh vertices around the same positions as the man. That should be better after that.